# Best way to receive new messages in a IM style app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

At the moment I am just querying the server every 3 seconds to see if there are any new messages using an NSURLRequest and such. If there are it saves them to the database and sends an NSNotificationCenter notification if there aren't then it just waits 3 seconds and tries again.

Is this the best way to do it? I realise (form posts on here and information elsewhere) that opening a persistant connection to the server is tedius and not reccommended, so would this be the best way to do it?

My main worry is that if there are no new messages its downloading an empty (of information, but still a few bytes big) XML feed, and running this every 3 seconds is going to add up eventually and use a lot of data.

Any pointers would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

XMPP would do this with a long-living TCP connection. How about using an XMPP service?

Comment: done and done. :) brilliant - especially with the extra XML. :)

Answer (score 1):

One of my own apps that I have written is an IM client and the app we develop at work also has IM features.

My own app uses a direct socket connection and TCP for communication. The TCP connection is kept alive with heart beat messages.

On the other hand, the app at work uses an XMPP based solution, which is fundamentally the same in that it uses a TCP or UDP connection, only instead of a proprietary protocol (in the case of my own IM app), XML messages are sent back and forth.

It depends how your server is currently implemented? Is this simply a chat implementation for your app only, or is it available to other users that may not be using an iPhone app? Would it be feasible for you to change the implementation on the server without breaking anything?

Comment: At the moment my server is as implemented as my app is. All I do is I have a php script chucking out XML. When the new messages arrive the XML updates to show the new messages and the iPhone downloads them. Everything is easy to change, and I think XMPP looks like the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Are [push notifications](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Introduction/Introduction.html) an options for your app?

Comment: yes they are, but this is an in-app thing - so if the app is running I want it to update in real time without push notifications. Obviously if the app is closed then push notifications are necessary.

Comment: Alright, forget my answer. This is surely the way to do this on an iPhone.

Comment: Note that they are by design unreliable and not guaranteed to arrive or arrive in a timely manner. They may get lost, they may come in hours later, and if you send a bunch of them you sometimes only receive the last. A persistent TCP connection with a nice protocol like XMPP is the way to go (heck, even a homebrewn protocol would do, but the TCP connection should be persistent).